# Django not looking for templates in the correct directory

Tags: django, templates

I have one existing Django project, which works fine. I made a new one then, based on the original one (not copying, only using the structure) and I have a problem with the new one.

In the app in the new project I have a folder templates and in that one another folder with app name. But this doesn't load the template if I reference it as 'app/index.html' in the view.

My `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is set to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` just as it is with the first project, which works. The directory structure is the same. But when I get the debug message I can see that it's trying to load templates from `ROOT/templates/app/index.html` instead of `ROOT/app/templates/app/index.html`.

What I at the end find out to be working was, to est `TEMPLATE_DIRS` to `BASE_DIR` only and then reference the complete path to the template as `'app/templates/app/index.html'`. But this is tedious and obviously not correct.

In neither of the apps am I using `TEMPLATE_LOADERS`, it's all default. What else can I check?

I'm using Django 1.6.1 on Python 2.7.

Comment: What's your `BASE_DIR` setting and directory structure? Looks like you're going one directory too far in your `BASE_DIR`

Comment: BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)) So it goes only to the main project's actual root dir.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your TEMPLATE_DIRS, I would expect it to look under `/full/path/to/base_dir/templates`, not `/full/path/to/base_dir/app/templates`

If the latter is what you want, use

`os.path.join(BASE_DIR', 'app', 'templates')`

Comment: But I have the same setting in another app, where it works properly and looks in 'app/templates/app/index.html' after being referenced 'app/index.html' in the view.

Comment: I doubt it. There's likely a subtle change you're overlooking.

Answer (score 2):

Most often this kind of errors happens when we name the templates folder wrong inside our app. Check whether it is named correctly as **"templates"**. *django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader* looks for a folder named *templates* inside our app folder

i.e,

```
app/
     templates/
               app/
                   index.html
```

Also make sure that you have correctly defined your app name inside INSTALLED_APPS as **'app_name.apps.App_nameConfig'**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [    
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'app_name.apps.App_nameConfig']
```